# Birationally transforming general curve of genus 1 to Weierstrass form

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry

> What are general rules to **birationally** transform general curve of any
>   degree of genus 1 to Weierstrass form, provided we have one rational
>   point?

Example of curve of degree 12:

$$x^9 y^3+9 x^9 y^2+27 x^9 y+27 x^9+9 x^8 y^3+81 x^8 y^2+243 x^8 y+243 x^8+35 x^7 y^3+318 x^7 y^2+963 x^7 y+972 x^7+74 x^6 y^3+687 x^6 y^2+2124 x^6 y+2187 x^6+90 x^5 y^3+871 x^5 y^2+2799 x^5 y+2988 x^5+67 x^4 y^3+692 x^4 y^2+2358 x^4 y+2655 x^4+39 x^3 y^3+415 x^3 y^2+1466 x^3 y+1717 x^3+21 x^2 y^3+211 x^2 y^2+723 x^2 y+840 x^2+4 x y^3+47 x y^2+180 x y+228 x-3 y^3-20 y^2-40 y-20=0$$

This curve has (geometric) genus 1. It has rational point $(-3, -\frac{17}{5})$.

I am familiar with transforming $y^2=a x^4+b x^3+c x^2+d x+e$ to Weierstrass form but have never seen similar process for curves of higher degree than $4$.

Comment: Find $y$ with only one triple pole at some point $p$, take $x$ with only one double pole at $p$, normalize it such that $y^2/x^3(p) = 1$, then $y^2-x^3$ is a linear combination of $yx,x^2,y,x,C$ (subtract the poles until it is simple, in genus one this implies it is constant) ie. $(y+dx+e)^2 = x^3+cx^2+bx+a$.

Comment: @reuns: I will try, I hope I can follow it. Is it a method that would work with any curve of genus 1 or you adapted the method to fit my example? And also as I understand it the method is dependent on finding specific point $p$ that could be hard to find because of its big height, my point in my example would not work. Am I right?

Comment: @reuns: At $y=-3$ there is a triple pole. But I think there are no double poles for any $x$. I found simple poles for $x=-2.1013...$, $x=-1.6485..$, $x=0.2392...$. Not sure you are talking about such poles... It would be great if you can provide explicit example or literature where there is an explicit example of how to do all the process.

Comment: @reuns: I found $y\to \frac{-10 x-10 y}{(x+3)^3},x\to \frac{6 x-10 y}{(x+3)^2}$. $y$ has triple pole, $x$ has double pole at $(-3, -\frac{17}{5})$. $y^2/x^3=1$ at $(-3, -\frac{17}{5})$ as required. $\left(\frac{-10 x-10 y}{(x+3)^3}\right)^2-\left(\frac{6 x-10 y}{(x+3)^2}\right)^3=-\frac{4 \left(54 x^3-270 x^2 y-25 x^2+450 x y^2-50 x y-250 y^3-25 y^2\right)}{(x+3)^6}$. How to proceed? I do not see how it is linear combination of what you wrote above.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have any other pole

Comment: $y$ has triple pole at $x=-3$ and $x$ has double pole at $x=-3$ - that is all I can see, if you could be more specific where I should see other poles...

Comment: Is there only one $y$ such that $(-3,y)$ is on the curve, is $x+3$ an uniformizer there

Comment: @reuns: Then $\{x,y\}=\left\{\frac{\left(111 y^2+706 y+1123\right)^2 (6 x-10 y)}{(x+3)^2},\frac{\left(111 y^2+706 y+1123\right)^3 (-10 x-10 y)}{(x+3)^3}\right\}$ will work? $y^2/x^3=1$ and poles are only at $(-3, -\frac{17}{5})$. And $y^2-x^3=-\frac{4 \left(111 y^2+706 y+1123\right)^6 \left(54 x^3-270 x^2 y-25 x^2+450 x y^2-50 x y-250 y^3-25 y^2\right)}{(x+3)^6}$. How to proceed?

Comment: Why do you care ?? This is a terrible example to understand how to find the genus of a singular curve and the Riemann Roch problem in this setting.

Comment: Whether it is a terrible example or not - the fact is that it can be transformed into cubic. That is what I want to know how to do it. My question was about general genus 1 curve, so I guess there are even more terrible examples of genus 1 curves. If you know a better example of degree at least $5$ then you may post it here.

Comment: Maybe [_An_ _algorithm_ _for_ _computing_ _the_ _Weierstrass_ _normal_ _form_
M Van Hoeij - ISSAC, 1995](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/compalg/IntBasis/Weierstrass.pdf) and the algcurves Maple package can help.

Comment: There are steps in the algorithm that I am not able to follow. A bit more detailed explanations would be needed. And also I do not have Maple.

Comment: `with(algcurves):`
`f := -20+228*x-40*y+x^9*y^3+9*x^9*y^2+27*x^9*y+9*x^8*y^3+81*x^8*y^2+243*x^8*y+35*x^7*y^3+318*x^7*y^2+963*x^7*y+74*x^6*y^3+687*x^6*y^2+2124*x^6*y+90*x^5*y^3+27*x^9-3*y^3-20*y^2+243*x^8+972*x^7+2187*x^6+2988*x^5+871*x^5*y^2+2799*x^5*y+67*x^4*y^3+692*x^4*y^2+2358*x^4*y+39*x^3*y^3+415*x^3*y^2+1466*x^3*y+21*x^2*y^3+211*x^2*y^2+723*x^2*y+4*x*y^3+47*x*y^2+180*x*y+2655*x^4+1717*x^3+840*x^2:`
`alias(alpha = RootOf(20+40*_Z+3*_Z^3+20*_Z^2)):`
`Weierstrassform(f, x, y, x0, y0);`

[maple output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMVO.png)

Comment: We want birational transformation. So even Maple can not do it?

Comment: [The whole maple output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6WqS.png)

Comment: That is OK, but it is not a birational transformation.

Comment: `Weierstrassform(f, x, y, x0, y0, [-3, -17/5, 1])` [maple output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBkf1.png)

Comment: The transformations are not **birational** but rather one transformation is one way rational and the other is another way. For example point on the given cubic $\{\text{x0},\text{y0}\}=\left\{\frac{256}{75},\frac{512}{125}\right\}$ if you plug it into the first transformation you will not get rational solution, you have to use the second transformation. If the transformations were birational then it would not matter into which transformation you plug in rational point - you would get rational solution in either cases. But at least something... though we do not know how the result was achieved.

Comment: [The help page](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves%2FWeierstrassform)

Answer (score 1):

$$C: x^9 y^3+9 x^9 y^2+27 x^9 y+27 x^9+9 x^8 y^3+81 x^8 y^2+243 x^8 y+243 x^8+35 x^7 y^3+318 x^7 y^2+963 x^7 y+972 x^7+74 x^6 y^3+687 x^6 y^2+2124 x^6 y+2187 x^6+90 x^5 y^3+871 x^5 y^2+2799 x^5 y+2988 x^5+67 x^4 y^3+692 x^4 y^2+2358 x^4 y+2655 x^4+39 x^3 y^3+415 x^3 y^2+1466 x^3 y+1717 x^3+21 x^2 y^3+211 x^2 y^2+723 x^2 y+840 x^2+4 x y^3+47 x y^2+180 x y+228 x-3 y^3-20 y^2-40 y-20=0$$

$$E: v^2=u^3+2 u^2+3 u+7$$

$$C\to E: \{x,y\}=\left\{\frac{2-u-v}{u+v},\frac{(3 u-3 v+2) (u+v)^2+24}{(v-u) (u+v)^2-8}\right\}$$
$$E\to C: \{u,v\}=\left\{\frac{-x^3 y-3 x^3-3 x^2 y-9 x^2-3 x y-10 x-1}{(x+1) (y+3)},\frac{x^3 y+3 x^3+3 x^2 y+9 x^2+3 x y+10 x+2 y+7}{(x+1) (y+3)}\right\}$$

Comment: May I know the source of your 'big' curve? Where it came from? Any general way to construct such higher degree elliptic curves?

Comment: The most easy way for example: $(x+3)^2 (x+4)^2 (x+5)^1 (y-3)^2-(x-5)^3 (x+1)^1 (x-2)^1 (y+4)^2$. Add random double, triple... roots and check whether it has genus 1. But this way you will not produce every possible type of genus 1 curve. There are also curves of genus 1 that have more complex set of singularities and also singularities at points of infinity. And "my curve" was also produced randomly by PC but with a different method.

Comment: Where to add more terms exactly? I tried to multiply first term by $(x-9)$ and second term by $(x- 8)$ but genus increases.

Comment: You could multiply with $(x-9)^2$ and $(x-8)^2$ for example, if the genus was more than 1.

Comment: This was just a quick and easy way. There are more elaborate ways, but it can not be explained in a comment.

Comment: Or $(1+x)^2*(2+x)^5*(-3+y)^3-(-1+x)^4*(5+y)^3$.

Comment: Or $(x+1)^3 (y-3)^5-(x-1)^5 (y+5)^4$.

Comment: How did you find that nice birational transformation? Maple doesn't produce anything like this!

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember. I think I was trying lots of different rational points and then done lots of manipulation until I found the simplest transformation. If I find my old notes about how I did it I will update my post.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone would be interested in Maple's result obtained by user [Jan-Magnus Økland](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28956/jan-magnus-%C3%98kland), I rewrote it by hand and simplified a bit:

```
x0^3+(4096/375)*x0-39583744/421875+y0^2=0

{x0=(-64*(459-2883*x-9835*x^2-10922*x^3+911*x^4+32019*x^5+79032*x^6+
107703*x^7+90099*x^8+47466*x^9+15525*x^10+2916*x^11+243*x^12+477*y-
1650*x*y-5739*x^2*y-4926*x^3*y+2229*x^4*y+18462*x^5*y+46482*x^6*y+
66672*x^7*y+57789*x^8*y+31104*x^9*y+10296*x^10*y+1944*x^11*y+162*x^12*y+
108*y^2-243*x*y^2-867*x^2*y^2-468*x^3*y^2+684*x^4*y^2+2697*x^5*y^2+
6786*x^6*y^2+10281*x^7*y^2+9255*x^8*y^2+5094*x^9*y^2+1707*x^10*y^2+
324*x^11*y^2+27*x^12*y^2))/(75*(1+x)^2*(3+x)^2),
y0=(512*(843-2710*x-16519*x^2-12074*x^3+53732*x^4+202061*x^5+420043*x^6+
605147*x^7+603976*x^8+410519*x^9+186465*x^10+54489*x^11+9342*x^12+
720*x^13+663*y-1555*x*y-10411*x^2*y-5199*x^3*y+37741*x^4*y+122433*x^5*y+
248798*x^6*y+368668*x^7*y+380591*x^8*y+265351*x^9*y+122554*x^10*y+
36166*x^11*y+6228*x^12*y+480*x^13*y+117*y^2-252*x*y^2-1708*x^2*y^2-
447*x^3*y^2+6786*x^4*y^2+18853*x^5*y^2+36789*x^6*y^2+55939*x^7*y^2+
59835*x^8*y^2+42846*x^9*y^2+20133*x^10*y^2+6001*x^11*y^2+1038*x^12*y^2+
80*x^13*y^2))/(125*(1+x)^2*(3+x)^3)}

{x=(-3*(641990656-26112000*x0+23400000*x0^2+421875*x0^3-18432000*y0+
4050000*x0*y0))/(1493958656+4608000*x0+81000000*x0^2+421875*x0^3),
y=-((12471594100595144366690926592+1955419142592015308213452800*x0+
1878075405942780183183360000*x0^2+317367943168385875968000000*x0^3+
100956115396303257600000000*x0^4+10300549541068800000000000*x0^5+
1553373542016000000000000*x0^6+92061983700000000000000*x0^7+
1575601083984375000000*x0^8+6382198333740234375*x0^9-
85483495844938839490560000*y0+18695958056411332608000000*x0*y0-
10870651215214018560000000*x0^2*y0+2004895847153664000000000*x0^3*y0-
253485556531200000000000*x0^4*y0+35822535120000000000000*x0^5*y0+
1409384812500000000000*x0^6*y0-33397668457031250000*x0^7*y0)/
(4064816181869106669044105216+616121378211946711272652800*x0+
627407206768386936668160000*x0^2+103220483647881609216000000*x0^3+
34217094666623385600000000*x0^4+3521701778227200000000000*x0^5+
545117693184000000000000*x0^6+34660450800000000000000*x0^7+
680639677734375000000*x0^8+1877117156982421875*x0^9))}
```